# Predicate Logic - Is my answer correct?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Construct a predicate logic proof equivalent to the following natural language
argument.
“No athletes are bookworms. Carol is a bookworm. Therefore Carol is not an athlete.”

Could someone please help with my symbols?

Ans.

Let $A(x)$ mean that $x$ is an athlete.
Let $B(x)$ mean that $x$ is a bookworm.
Let Constant $C$ denote Carol

$\forall x, A(x) \implies \neg B(x), B(C), \neg A(C)$.

Is this correct? I know we will have to apply rules down after this—but is my beginning even correct?

I sometimes feel that my starting statement should be

$\forall x, A(x) \implies \neg B(x), B(C), \iff \neg A(C)$.

Is this correct?

Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Hi, I don't quite understand you notation. It take it that $-A(C)$ means $\neg A(C)$, i.e., not $A(C)$). Is $A(x) = -B(x)$ supposed to be $A(x) \implies \neg B(x)$ or $A(x) \iff \neg B(x)$?

Comment: Thanks. 
My statement supposed to mean V(x),(A(x)=>¬B(x)),B(C),¬A(C) 
With your help.

Comment: If you want to write well-formatted formulas, you should consider using MathJax, see here: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation. I edited your question to use it - look at the source to see what I've done.

Comment: Thank you. I will learn this to make my statement better. But for starters, Am I in the right track? This Q is from MCGraw Hill 2011 - Predicate Logic and I cant seem to solve it? :(

Comment: @JohannesKloos There is still some funky gray box in the source I can't identify, in the line following "denote Carol".

Comment: @dfeuer: I suppose that comes from the OP's edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The task here, it seems to me, is to construct a *proof*, that validates the argument you are given in natural language. So you need premises, and you need a desired conclusion. So your premises are $$\begin{align} & (1)\quad\forall x, A(x) \Rightarrow \lnot B(x) \\ \\ & (2) \quad B(C)\end{align}$$

Then, from these premises, you need to construct a proof which leads you to the *conclusion:*

$$\therefore \lnot A(C)$$

For example, you'd need to use universal instantiation on premise $(1)$ to infer $$(3) \quad A(C) \Rightarrow \lnot B(C)$$

Now you can simply use $(3)$ and premise $(2)$ to conclude, by modus tollens, that therefore, $(4)\quad \lnot A(C)$, though you might want to add a fourth step, double negation on premise $(2)$ to get $\lnot \lnot B(C)$, and then employ modus tollens to arrive at the conclusion.
This argument form, as given in natural language, is called a syllogism, which has the form:$$\begin{align} \quad & \text{No A is a B}\\ \\  \quad & \text{C is a B}\\  & \hline \\ \\  \therefore & \text{C is not an A}\end{align}$$

Comment: A lot of logic problems right up your alley! +1

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is not quite correct, but you're close. Let's take your answer apart:

$\forall x, A(x) \implies \neg B(x),A(C),\neg B(x)$ collects three statements. The first is "any $x$ that is an athlete is not a bookworm", the second means "C is a bookworm" and the third means "C is not an athlete. These parts are correct.

What is missing is that you need to match the original form of the argument. In particular, the statement is "therefore, Carol is not an athlete", whereas the "therefore" does not appear in your formalization. However, this points directly to the right solution: You need to tie the three statements together with logical connectives.

As a pointer on how to solve this, consider the following example: When I formalize "All cats are animals. Therefore, the cat Delila is an animal", a possible formalization would be $(\forall x, \mathsf{Cat}(x) \implies \mathsf{Animal}(x)) \implies (\mathsf{Cat}(\mathsf{Delila}) \implies \mathsf{Animal}(\mathsf{Delila}))$. Can you figure out the solution from here?

**EDIT**: The question was modified after this answer was posed. The expression $\forall x, A(x) \implies \neg \neg B(x), B(C), \iff \neg A(C)$ is not well-defined: writing $\iff P$ is like writing $= 0$, so it's not clear what you second attempt is supposed to mean.

Comment: ∀x,A(x)⟹¬B(x),B(C),B(C)⟹¬A(C)

Is this correct?

Comment: Strictly speaking, this seems to be a correct answer. But two questions remain: 1. What on earth do all these commas mean? 2. Why is there a lone $B(C)$ floating around in you formula?

Comment: Should the commas be replaced by the ^ sign? I have to prove this statement. Also, that lone B(C) was the actual statement that Carol is a bookworm . But if it has to be removed, I understand that too. Ill remove it and make my sentence look just like - 

∀x,A(x)⟹¬B(x),B(C)⟹¬A(C)

Comment: It may be helpful to think about what the different symbols actually mean. Basically, $A \land B$ means that both $A$ and $B$ are true (usually independently of each other). This means that to prove $(\forall x, A(x) \implies \neg B(x)) \land (B(C) \implies \neg A(C))$, you would have to prove two statements, one being $\forall x, A(x) \implies \neg B(x)$ - this is probably not what you want. On the other hand, $\implies$ can be used to build arguments with assumptions and conclusions: $A \implies B$ means "assuming $A$, $B$ is true" or "Suppose $A$. Therefore $B$." [cont'd...]

Comment: [...cont'd] So, one way of formalizing your statement would be $(\forall x, A(x) \implies \neg B(x)) \implies B(C) \implies \neg A(C)$. Another would be $((\forall x, A(x) \implies \neg B(x)) \land B(C)) \implies \neg A(C)$. (Small remark on the side: actually, the statement is slightly different, and should be formulated using $\models$, but I don't known if you have come far enough for that already).

Comment: Yes I have come across that symbol. What is your recommendation about which statement to use incase I have to construct a predicate logic proof? I have to use Universe Instantiation. + Double Negation + Modus T rules (Hints given by Question book). But from my understanding, the ⊨ symbol comes at the start of the sentence.

Comment: If you have $\models$ available, write the whole thing as $\{ (\forall x, A(x) \implies \neg B(X)), B(C) \} \models \neg A(C)$. The mentioned rules give you the result you want.

Comment: Thank you @Johannes. You are a very kind man.